# find the largest int in shared preferences

Tags: android, int, sharedpreferences

I have 8 numbers stored in my shared prefrences im trying to figure out how to recignize wich on is the largest and display in a textview?

edit:

```
private void showKing(){
    SharedPreferences peepsScores = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int userScore1 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore1",222);
    int userScore2 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore2",222);
    int userScore3 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore3",222);
    int userScore4 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore4",222);
    int userScore5 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore5",222);
    int userScore6 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore6",222);
    int userScore7 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore7",222);
    int userScore8 = peepsScores.getInt("userScore8",222);


    String pDName1 =  pName1.getText().toString();
    String pDName2 =  pName2.getText().toString();
    String pDName3 =  pName3.getText().toString();
    String pDName4 =  pName4.getText().toString();
    String pDName5 =  pName5.getText().toString();
    String pDName6 =  pName6.getText().toString();
    String pDName7 =  pName7.getText().toString();
    String pDName8 =  pName8.getText().toString();

    if(userScore1>userScore2+userScore3+userScore4+userScore5+userScore6+userScore7+userScore8){
        dPresident.setText(pDName1);
    }
        else{

    if(userScore2>userScore1+userScore3+userScore4+userScore5+userScore6+userScore7+userScore8){
        dPresident.setText(pDName2);
    }
        else{

    if(userScore3>userScore2+userScore1+userScore4+userScore5+userScore6+userScore7+userScore8){
        dPresident.setText(pDName3);
    }
        else{

    if(userScore4>userScore2+userScore3+userScore1+userScore5+userScore6+userScore7+userScore8){
        dPresident.setText(pDName4);
    }
        else{

    if(userScore5>userScore2+userScore3+userScore4+userScore1+userScore6+userScore7+userScore8){
        dPresident.setText(pDName5);
    }
        else{

    if(userScore6>userScore2+userScore3+userScore4+userScore5+userScore1+userScore7+userScore8){
        dPresident.setText(pDName6);
    }
        else{

    if(userScore7>userScore2+userScore3+userScore4+userScore5+userScore6+userScore1+userScore8){
        dPresident.setText(pDName7);
    }
        else{

    if(userScore8>userScore2++userScore3&userScore4&&userScore5+userScore6+userScore7+userScore1){
        dPresident.setText(pDName8);

    }
    }}}}}}}
}
```

in number 8 I was trying other symbols and eclipse says no

Comment: Hmmm....and what is the problem? You can simply compare them.

Comment: Hmmmm ftech every record and compare in simple logic manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
//Obtain highest Score (Select maximum value)
int highestScore = Math.max(userScore1 ,  
   Math.max(userScore2 ,  
      Math.max(userScore3 ,  
           Math.max(userScore4 , 
               Math.max(userScore5 ,  
                 Math.max(userScore6 , 
                     Math.max(userScore7 , userScore8)))))));

// set text
dPresident.setText("" + highestScore);
```

Comment: worked like a dream doomsknight thank you

Answer (score 1):

Incredibly elegant if I may say so myself :P

```
int maxnumber = 0;

for (int i = 1; i >= 8; i++) {
            maxnumber = Math.max(peepsScores.getInt("userScore" + i, 0), maxnumber);
        }
```

Now `maxnumber` will be equal to the highest number.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I was overthinking it:

```
if(userScore1 > userScore2 + userScore3 + userScore4 + userScore5 + userScore6 + userScore7 + userScore8) {
    dPresident.setText("" + userScore1);
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: @Cole. This is far from the correct answer. He has compared one number, to the sum of the others. Rather than compare them for the biggest. :|

Comment: yah i just ran it and figured that out ive tryed putting the and symbol in there and other things then i was going to convert it to an all them to an array and use the findLargest method but i dont know how to make an array adapter ill do an a edit and post my full method

Comment: @Doomsknight well, my general idea is that if the OP puts an answer to his own question, tell him to mark it without examining it.